# Inconsistent response fetching data from Google Sheet via local react app

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, fetch

I've made a create-react-app that I build and run statically on my machine as an OBS plugin with no server using Hashrouter.  I'm fetching data from a Google Sheet that I have set to public.  Using a url in this format `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/{SpreadsheetID}/{sheetNo}/public/values?alt=json` I'm able to fetch data as JSON to use in my app. However, the responses have become inconsistent in the past week with no changes to the app.

When I go to the URL in a browser, it never fails to load a plain text version of the JSON.  However, when sending a GET request in my app, I get at 404 error 60% of the time. I've tried different headers in my request, but I can't seem to find anything that works consistently.

Here's the function where I do the fetch. I'm calling this from within a useEffect hook.

```
const getData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`fetch error. status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

The 404 response I get says: "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again."

I figure it has something to do with the fact that I'm calling from a local file without a server running.  I'd like to keep it this way if possible just to make things simple for OBS operators.  I've tried adding an API key to my fetch url (`key={APIKEY}`) but that didn't seem to make any difference. Any thoughts on what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: To follow up, the link in @MattKing's answer below has an accepted answer that is working for me now.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347/retrieving-data-from-sheets-results-in-404-error-50-of-the-time?hl=en&msgid=121557699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem.  Please see this thread.
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347

Comment: Thanks so much!  Not what I wanted to hear, but at least it’s not just me. I must level up my Googling skills.