# Getting data out of a google sheet

Tags: php, api, google-sheets

I use a script in a cronjob to grab data from a google spreadsheet. It worked fine for over a year but recently started giving occasional 404s and now gives 404 every time.

I don't care how I get the data out, I just need a way my script can get the data.

Right now I'm using this URL to get data but I really don't care how I get it so long as it's machine readable and automated. https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1KxpfpHzCstsg_hvG8v6ksgjt3ghAHb1URwW41mW7Vgs/1/public/full?alt=json

My script is PHP at a URL called by a cron job every 15 minutes (yeah, that isn't very tight design, I know!)

Comment: This is a known problem. See my answer there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819062/inconsistent-response-fetching-data-from-google-sheet-via-local-react-app

Answer (score 1):

**Looks like what you are experiencing might in fact be a bug.**

I suggest you star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196754560) on Google's Issue Tracker as any updates regarding this will be posted there.

## Update

Seems that this is the expected behavior in this situation as the Sheets API v3 has been deprecated and it would have been removed on the 3rd of March 2020. However, this deadline has been extended to 2nd of August 2021 - hence, the errors you are receiving now.

In order to fix this, you will have to migrate your application to Sheets API v4.

#### Reference

- [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration);
- [Sheets API v3 deprecation timeline](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the easy solution for me is to just move to using a CSV export instead; https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KxpfpHzCstsg_hvG8v6ksgjt3ghAHb1URwW41mW7Vgs/export?format=csv&id=1KxpfpHzCstsg_hvG8v6ksgjt3ghAHb1URwW41mW7Vgs&gid=2091339502 as I just want the contents of the cells, I don't need any of the other info.

(an alternative would be to move to the v4 API instead but I can't be bothered if it broke once it'll break again)