# MIGRATE GOOGLE SHEETS API TO V4 FROM V3

Tags: json, web, google-sheets

I was able to access a google sheet using the spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells....method but it has suddenly stopped working. I am getting a 404 error now.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent response fetching data from Google Sheet via local react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819062/inconsistent-response-fetching-data-from-google-sheet-via-local-react-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following format for v4 API call

[https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'sheetID'/values/'worksheet_name'?key='KEY'](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%27sheetID%27/values/%27worksheet_name%27?key=%27KEY%27)

Answer (score 3):

#### In order to prevent this, you will have to migrate to Sheets API v4.

In fact, the behavior you are seeing right now is the expected one as Sheets API v3 is currently deprecated and has shut down on 2nd of August 2021. The error you are receiving is due to this.

[image]

As for the migration, you might want to take a look at this article [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v3-api) as instructions and steps you should take for this are included.

#### Reference

- [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v3-api) ;
- [Sheets API v3 deprecation timeline](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api).

Comment: Thanks Ale13. Does this mean I now have to install the API in my app? I was previously able to run a simple fetch call and get a json response without the need for an API key as the sheet was published and available publicly.

Comment: How does your request look like?

Comment: Previously I just did a GET request for the following: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/YOURGOOGLESHEETCODE/SHEETPAGENUMBER/public/full?alt=json

Response would be a JSON object that contained the spreadsheet data. I did not have to add any keys, install APIs, etc. You could even just go the URL in Chrome and see the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getJson(id,gid){
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return(json)
}
```

- with id of the spreadsheet and gid of your sheet (may be 0)
- note that first row is dedicated to labels, then rows[0] corresponds to row#2 and c[0] corresponds to column A
- if you want to retrieve B1 (column 2 row 1) : `json.cols[1].label`
- if you want to retrieve B2 (column 2 row 2) : `json.rows[0].c[1].v`

Answer (score 0):

I had a few webapps that used the old version, just upgraded to V4 using this formatted url:
[https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+worksheet_id+'/values/'+tab_name+'?alt=json&key='+key-value](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%27+worksheet_id+%27/values/%27+tab_name+%27?alt=json&key=%27+key-value)

worksheet_id is still the same id
tab is now the tab NAME, not the id
key is the API key from console (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

(reference: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347/retrieving-data-from-sheets-results-in-404-error-50-of-the-time)

Crucially the format of the json is quite different, so you may need to recode your parser. The new format is simpler.